# Custom ListView Design with horizontal CardView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

- In one of my applications, I have following design for favourite contacts. I'm fetching favourite contacts from phone and displaying them as attached design by using Custom List adapter. But the problem is in both of the sections contacts are repeated. For example if there are eight favourite contacts then it should display four lines by setting contacts horizontally. But it is fetching all eight contacts and displaying the same contact in each row.
- I hope I'm clearing my point, what I want. Here is my code, I know I am doing something wrong. I have tried numerous methods but nothing works.

  [image: Layout Design]

**Fragment Favourite**

```
public class FragmentFavourites extends Fragment{

ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView f_list;
String starred_id,starred_name,starred_number;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourites, container, false);
    f_list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fav_list);
    name.clear();
    number.clear();
    getFavourites();
    return rootView;

}

public void getFavourites()
{
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED}, ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED + "='1'", null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        starred_id = cur.getString(0);
        starred_name = cur.getString(1);
        name.add(starred_name);
        starred_number=getFavouriteNumber(starred_id);
        number.add(starred_number);

    }
    cur.close();

    FavouriteAdapter fa=new FavouriteAdapter(getActivity(),name,number);
    f_list.setAdapter(fa);
}

public String getFavouriteNumber(String contactId)
{
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    String phone=null;

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
            new String[]{contactId}, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        phone=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }

    cursor.close();
    return phone;
 }
}
```

**FavouriteAdapter**

```
public class FavouriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Activity context;
ArrayList<String> f_name,f_number;
//String[] name1,name2,number1,number2;
TextView tf_name,tf_number,main_letter,tf_name_t,tf_number_t,main_letter_t;
int i;
int flag=1,count;

FavouriteAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> fav_name, ArrayList<String> fav_number){

    this.context=context;
    this.f_name=fav_name;
    this.f_number=fav_number;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return f_name.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {

    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater l=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View row=l.inflate(R.layout.favourite_adapter_layout,null,true);

    /*name1=new String[f_name.size()];
    name2=new String[f_name.size()];
    number1=new String[f_number.size()];
    number2=new String[f_number.size()];*/

    main_letter=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.main_letter);
    tf_name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.favName);
    tf_number=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.favNumber);
    tf_name_t=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.favName_t);
    tf_number_t=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.favNumber_t);
    main_letter_t=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.main_letter_t);
    count=f_name.size();

    try {
        if(flag==1)
        {
        for (int i=0;i<f_name.size();i++){

            if(i==count) {

                flag=0;
                break;
            }

            if(i%2==0){
                    System.out.println("i in One: "+i);
                tf_name.setText(f_name.get(position));
                tf_number.setText(f_number.get(position));
                if (!f_name.get(position).isEmpty()) {
                    String init = f_name.get(position).substring(0, 1);
                    main_letter.setText(init);
                }

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("i in Two: "+i);
                tf_name_t.setText(f_name.get(position));
                tf_number_t.setText(f_number.get(position));
                if (!f_name.get(position).isEmpty()) {
                    String init = f_name.get(position).substring(0, 1);
                    main_letter_t.setText(init);

            }
        }

    }}}
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return row;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why you are not using a `GridView` with custom adapter?!

Comment: Hmm Ok, I will try to implement this design with custom GridView that will definitely work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have used `GridView` to solve my problem instead of `ListView`. Here is my piece of Code. Hope it will help Somebody Else.

**FragmentFavourites**

```
    public class FragmentFavourites extends Fragment{

ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<String>();
GridView f_list;
String starred_id,starred_name,starred_number;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourites, container, false);
    f_list=(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
    name.clear();
    number.clear();
    try
    {
        new GetFavouriteTask().execute();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Problem Loading Contacts",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;

}

public class GetFavouriteTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getFavourites();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        try {
            FavouriteAdapter fa=new FavouriteAdapter(getActivity(),name,number);
            f_list.setAdapter(fa);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}

public void getFavourites()
{
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED}, ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED + "='1'", null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        starred_id = cur.getString(0);
        starred_name = cur.getString(1);
        name.add(starred_name);
        starred_number=getFavouriteNumber(starred_id);
        number.add(starred_number);

    }
    cur.close();
}

public String getFavouriteNumber(String contactId)
{
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    String phone=null;

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
            new String[]{contactId}, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        phone=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }

    cursor.close();
    return phone;
}
}
```

**FavouriteAdapter**

```
    public class FavouriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Activity context;
ArrayList<String> f_name,f_number;
TextView tf_name,tf_number,main_letter;
int i;

FavouriteAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> fav_name, ArrayList<String> fav_number){
    this.context=context;
    this.f_name=fav_name;
    this.f_number=fav_number;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return f_name.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {

    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater l=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View row=l.inflate(R.layout.favourite_adapter_layout,null,true);


    main_letter=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.main_letter);
    tf_name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.favName);
    tf_number=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.favNumber);

    try {
                tf_name.setText(f_name.get(position));
                tf_number.setText(f_number.get(position));
                if (!f_name.get(position).isEmpty()) {
                    String init = f_name.get(position).substring(0, 1);
                    main_letter.setText(init);
                }}
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return row;
}
 }
```

**fragment_favourites.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**favourite_adapter_layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#02605c"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/main_letter"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/favName"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/favNumber"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
     </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```